# Boostrap html table with a lot of added things

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

Sorry for stupid question but I have been trying to make table in html that will: [image]

And be hover sensitive == when you hover over row its color will change.
I have tried searching but nothing is like I need... Thanks for any help.

Comment: Kindly go through the bs4 tables. Please use this link from w3schools for reference. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_tables.asp

Comment: Ok, I will look through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap offers a hoverable row table. Check out the [Bootstrap table documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/).

Here is the example code they show in the docs:

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will look through it